# XML/XSLT/HTML processor for Mac

Tags: html, xml, xslt

What is a good XML/XSLT Editor which is free? 
I had been using Oxygen and Editix but there are paid versions and I was wondering if there is a good XML/XSLT/HTML editor for Mac?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

"Processor", "Convertor" ? I assume you mean "Editor" with XSLT capabilities ?

I'd say [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/), which makes a pretty good editor once you have installed the XML/XSLT plugins :

> Matching tag actions, pretty-printing, graphical editing of tag
>   attributes and conversion of special characters to entities and vice
>   versa is supported for both XML and HTML files.
>
> XML files are validated against their DTD or XSD, and the element tree
>   is shown in a dockable window. Validation errors are shown in the
>   Error List.

It's free and made with Java, so available on Mac.

Please note that it's still far from Oxygen XML Editor in term of features.

Comment: @kowalski Sorry made the changes. Could you tell me a command line thing as well?

Comment: For XSLT processing on the command line, I recommend you to use the [Saxon library](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.3HE).

Comment: For XSLT processing on the command line, I recommend you to use xsltproc. its probably already installed.

Comment: I agree that xsltproc is a good choice if you don't need XSLT 2.0 support